# tagged page on tumblr infinite scroll

Tags: tags, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll, tumblr-themes

I am new user of the forum! And also a beginer in tumblr theme building!
So could you please be clement with me!

I would like to build a tumblr theme. I started from a theme called Field-Object. I use this theme for a photography blog with a lot of pictures collection. The tag option of this theme is very usefull.

My problem is the infinite scroll option with tag page. It doesn't work…
I have added an infinite scroll which works well in the block post page but there is bug with tag page which contains beyond 15 tags (= 15 pictures). For exemple if I have 16 pictures tagged on the page. There is a superimposition, the first picture will come above the 15 others. (you can see this problem demo[here](http://fascination-subjects.tumblr.com/tagged/004%E2%80%94USA%20flag))

I saw in your forum a quick answer for this problem with Tumblr API pagination, but I don't understand how I can do that. 
Or maybe you will have an other solution?

please find my tumblr code [here](http://pastebin.com/8yCKNV0e#)
Thank you in advance for your advice!